# IE page doesn't update - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

As far as I can see, there's nothing wrong with this code. Indeed, on one of my computers it works just fine, but on two others, it doesn't!  All three run Excel 2003 on different versions of windows (7, 8.1 and 10).

What it is supposed to do is activate a search, then load the results page and print the innerHTML of the results page. One one machine (win 8.1) it does just that. On the other two, it prints the innerHTML of the search page.

Do I just have to abandon my trusty Excel 2003? Or is it a problem with my windows install? The W10 machine is a clean install of W10.

I am at my wits end over this! so please help me. :)

```
'This uses early binding
'In menu at top of page - Tools...Reference.... Microsoft Internet Controls      and Microsoft HTML Object Library must both be ticked

Sub main()
sUrl = "https://www.insolvencydirect.bis.gov.uk/FIP1/"
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim doc, element
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True


For iii = Asc("A") To Asc("B")  ' *** test use B *** Do A-Z
aaa = Chr(iii)


IE.navigate sUrl

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = IE.document




 doc.getElementById("IPSurname").Value = aaa

 doc.forms.Item(0).elements(7).Click



'loading new page with data


Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set doc = IE.document

MyBit = doc.body.innerHTML
Debug.Print MyBit

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think your dealing with a timing issue on loading the second page.  If I step through your code it works fine but if I run it I get the same result you describe.  Haven't had time to play with a fix but maybe this will help lead you to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. And reproducing the error! I thought the idea of Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4 is to wait for the page to load fully. I'll put in a delay and try again, but I'm not truly convinced.

Comment: Well, I'll have to eat my words.Putting in a 2 second delay solves the issue. (Not 1 second - that's not long enough.)      Anybody care to explain why waiting for IE to be ready isn't enough, please?

Answer (score 0):

choose some element tag from the page and do  that :

```
.
.
IE.navigate sUrl
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set doc = IE.document

 Do While True 
If ie.document.getElementsByTagName("element tag").Length > 0 Then
 Exit Do
End If
  Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
 Loop
.
.
.
```